# Connect to MySql from an external IP

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have an Apache server on a computer (win server 2012) with IP "myApacheIP" and a MySQL server on an other computer (win server 2012) with IP "mySQLIP".

In the computer with Apache I installed PhpMyAdmin but I can't access to MySQL server.
Is not a firewall problem because it is turned off in both computers.
Is there anything that I have to configure?

Comment: Allow the Apache Servers IP address in the mysql settings (my.cnf) Set ``bind-address = APACHE_IP_ADDRESS``  and restart the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to update your `my.cnf` to explicitly allow remote connections.

You would do this by changing `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `#bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and then restarting your MySQL server.

You would then need to open your 3306 port on your firewall for your specific IP using something like:

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s YOUR_IP_ADDRESS -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT`